# Excel Generated by EPPlus is Corrupted

Tags: c#, .net, excel, ms-office, epplus

I'm using the following code to add a background image to Excel using EPPlus.The document opens fine in polaris office but when using Excel I get this error

> We found a problem with some content in 'filename.xlsx'. Do you want to try to recover as much as we can

Code:

```
foreach (var file in Filelist)
{
    // Load workbook
    //var fileInfo = new FileInfo(@file);
    FileStream fs = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);
                  
    //ExcelPackage pkg = new ExcelPackage(fs);
    using (var package = new ExcelPackage(fs))
    {
        // Iterate over workbook sheets
        foreach (var sheet in package.Workbook.Worksheets)
        {
            sheet.BackgroundImage.Image = bmp;
            sheet.Protection.IsProtected = false;
        }
    
        package.SaveAs(new FileInfo(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file)+".xlsx"));
    }

    fs.Close();
}
```

I checked related SO questions, some mentioned that the issue might be due to saving multiple times. I made sure that the loop is hit only once for a single file.

**Update**: code for bitmap generation:

```
using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
{
    g.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
    g.TextRenderingHint = System.Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.AntiAlias;         
    SizeF textSize = g.MeasureString("Sample", new Font(DefaultFont.FontFamily, 80));
    g.DrawString("Sample", new Font("Tahoma", 80), Brushes.Red, -(textSize.Width / 2), -(textSize.Height / 2));
}
```

Comment: Maybe you should put your `FileStream` in a `using` statement as well, however i doubt it is a problem

Comment: @MichaelRandall Tried it,does not fix the issue.

Comment: I'm getting this error when I use a NumberFormat of "e2". I need to format some numbers in scientific notation.

Comment: @KenWhite I don't use number format anywhere... that comment is from a different user....

Comment: What kind of image is it? Can you post it online somewhere?  If you run this code on a blank/new workbook does it work?  It could be a problem with the specific worksheet you are working on as epplus does not support all excel features.

Comment: @ErnieS Please see the update.

Comment: What usually helps me resolving those issues is to do it in Excel itself and then compare the two xml files within the zip package - that usually points me towards the solution

Answer (score 0):

Works fine in my example:

```
class EPPTest
{
public void CreateExcel(string filename)
{
    var fi = new FileInfo(filename);

    using (var excel = new ExcelPackage(fi) )
    using (var img = CreateImage() )
    {
        if( excel.Workbook.Worksheets.Count == 0 )
        {
            excel.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("MySheet");
        }

        foreach (var sheet in excel.Workbook.Worksheets)
        {

            sheet.BackgroundImage.Image = img;
            sheet.Protection.IsProtected = false;

        }

        excel.Save();// As(new FileInfo(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file) + ".xlsx"));
    }
}

public Image CreateImage()
{
    Bitmap img = new Bitmap(400, 400);

    using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(img))
    using ( Font f = new Font("Tahoma", 80))
    {
        g.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
        g.TextRenderingHint = System.Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.AntiAlias;
        SizeF textSize = g.MeasureString("Sample", f);
        g.DrawString("Sample", f, Brushes.Red, 0, (textSize.Height ));
    }

    return img;
}
```

}

Here is the output:
[image: Sample screenshot]

Comment: Thanks.. is the background of the generared image black?

Comment: Are you using Microsoft Excel?

Comment: yes - and regarding back: I used your code for image generation, but maybe this is influenced by the dark theme I use

Comment: Did this help you?

Comment: Why downvote? It is a correct example with a newly created file that I prove worked?

Comment: I also tried it with an existing (but emtpy file) and it works

Comment: @MarioTheSpoon is showing a working example of what OP exposed as a problem, he doesn't deserve a downvote!

Comment: @MarioTheSpoon Try with the sample excel provided by Microsoft https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=521962

Comment: I did a breif check and it also fails with my code. I checked the generated xml and it seems that also a lot of other format information is discarded. If I find some time, I will check in more detail in the evening (CET)